# How to include record after group by and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table that tracks likes for users. Now I get the top 4 by using this line:

```
Liked_item.group('name').order('count_id desc').count('id').take(4)
```

This results in an array like this:

```
=> [["Name1", 10], ["Name 2", 8], ["Name 3", 5], ["Name 4", 3]]
```

Now instead of just the name and the number I would like to include the full record (The likes are not tied to a model, that's why I have to group by :name). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a candidate for using a [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope):

```
class LikedItem
  scope :by_name, ->(name) { where(name: name) }
end
```

Usage:

```
LikeItem.by_name(name)
```

which will return you an ActiveRecord collection of all likes for given name.

If you indeed want to have a hash with name as key and list of like_items as value, you can use Ruby (which is not recommended):

```
LikeItem.all.group_by(&:name).each_with_object({}) do |(name, collection), hash|
  hash[name] = { collection: collection, count: collection.size }
end
```

Comment: But I'm not searching for a specific item, I am just looking at the table and picking the names that occur the most. With the line I have now I get that result but it only returns the name and count instead of the full record

Comment: @stoerebink I've edited the answer. See the last line

Comment: Thanks mate. Just wondering why the last line is not recommended?

edit: I just ran this in console and it does look better but it doesn't include the count

Comment: @stoerebink it can potentially overload the memory, because the whole collection of `LikeItem`s will be fetched into memory before starting the processing. Of course, if you have few hundreds or few thousands of like_items you will barely notice the difference, but having really a lot of these can cause you troubles. And in any way Ruby is much slower than database processing, so always try to find db solution when possible.

Comment: Perhaps a quicker way would be to query the DB for the top 4 items and then just do 4 lookups?

Comment: @stoerebink I like neither truly to say, so the decision is after you :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko hey, sorry it's not relatedto this question but, can you please help me with this

Comment: @DeepakMahakale I'm still working at the moment, so can't promise any help, but show me with what :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko What would be your preferred solution? I think the problem here is that the likes are not associated to a model but rather to items from an external api (I just keep track of the ID of the items)

Comment: @stoerebink there is not much I can add to the answer. Unless there is a database-based solution, you go with Ruby - simple as that :)